# Mismatch between sys.executable and sys.version in Python

Tags: python, linux, sudo, env

There are two Python interpreters installed:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ /usr/bin/python -V && /usr/local/bin/python -V
Python 2.4.3
Python 2.7.6
```

Sudo changes `PATH` for every command it runs as follows:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ env | grep PATH && sudo env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/user/bin
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
```

I run a test script:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ cat what_python.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
print sys.executable
print sys.version
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo python what_python.py
/usr/bin/python
2.7.6 (default, Feb 27 2014, 17:05:07) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)]
```

and get path to Python 2.4.3 in `sys.executable` and version 2.7.6 reported in `sys.version`. Clearly `sys.executable` and `sys.version` do not match. Taking into account how sudo modifies PATH I can understand the value of `sys.executable`. However, why does `sys.version` report version 2.7.6 and not version 2.4.3, which would match `usr/bin/python` path reported by `sys.executable`?

This is a follow-up to my question [Sudo changes PATH, yet executes the same binary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118312/)

Comment: Can you use `ls -l /usr/bin/python` and see if possibly it's pointing to a different executable when logged in as superuser? it would be weird, but it's possible.

Comment: My guess is that `sudo` does a PATH search for the binary to run using the users environment before it cleans the environment, sets the new PATH, and executes it. That might be by design, because, e.g. if a user is accustomed to using `gcc` version X that is in `/usr/local/something`, they might be surprised to see a different version when they run `sudo gcc`. And, as you've seen, `sudo` resets the environment before actually running the command, which seems to maybe break some Python assumptions...

Comment: @CorleyBrigman Output of `[user@localhost ~]$ sudo ls -l /usr/bin/python` is `-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 8304 Oct 23  2012 /usr/bin/python`

Comment: @twalberg *(…) which seems to maybe break some Python assumptions...* – I don't think so as a) I don't suspect sudo hides information about location of executable from process it runs and b) I don't think Python has to make any assumptions about location of its executable as in normal circumstances (including sudo) every process should know location of its executable i.e. this information is not hidden from it.

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost By that I meant it looks like `sys.executable` searches the current PATH instead of resolving `argv[0]` (or maybe because `argv[0]` is simpy `python` in this case...), which was not necessarily the executable that was spawned by `sudo`, because `sudo` changed PATH before invoking `python`, but after it resolved which `python` to invoke.

Comment: @twalberg, Piotr, the correct way for a Linux program to determine its executable is to resolve the link under `/proc/self/exe`. If `python` isn't doing this and is searching `PATH` instead, this would explain the disparity. You could check by writing a script which shows both the target of `/proc/self/exe` and `sys.executable` or use my suggestion below and check externally while the program is running.

Comment: @twalberg You were right – see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both @Graeme

> The fact that python may be unable to retrieve this suggests that it
>   is doing its own PATH search (…)

and @twalberg

> (…) it looks like sys.executable searches the current PATH instead of
>   resolving argv[0] (or maybe because argv[0] is simpy python in this
>   case...), (…)

were basically right. I was reluctant to believe that Python does something so simple (silly?) as using `PATH` to locate itself but this is true.

Python's `sys` module is implemented in `Python/sysmodule.c` file. As of version 2.7.6, `sys.executable` is set at line [1422](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Python/sysmodule.c#l1422) like this:

```
 SET_SYS_FROM_STRING("executable",
                     PyString_FromString(Py_GetProgramFullPath()));
```

`Py_GetProgramFullPath()` function is defined in file `Modules/getpath.c` starting from line [701](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Modules/getpath.c#l702):

```
char *
Py_GetProgramFullPath(void)
{
    if (!module_search_path)
        calculate_path();
    return progpath;
}
```

Function `calcuate_path()` is defined in the same file and contains the following [comment](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Modules/getpath.c#l415):

```
/* If there is no slash in the argv0 path, then we have to
 * assume python is on the user's $PATH, since there's no
 * other way to find a directory to start the search from.  If
 * $PATH isn't exported, you lose.
 */
```

As can be seen in my case, one loses also when the first Python on exported `$PATH` is different than the Python being run.

More information on the process of calculating placement of interpreter's executable can be found at the [top](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Modules/getpath.c#l28) of `getpath.c` file:

> Before any searches are done, the location of the executable is
>   determined.  If argv[0] has one or more slashes in it, it is used
>   unchanged.  Otherwise, it must have been invoked from the shell's path,
>   so we search $PATH for the named executable and use that.  If the
>   executable was not found on $PATH (or there was no $PATH environment
>   variable), the original argv[0] string is used.
>
> Next, the executable location is examined to see if it is a symbolic
>   link.  If so, the link is chased (correctly interpreting a relative
>   pathname if one is found) and the directory of the link target is used.

Let's make a couple of tests to verify the above:

*If argv[0] has one or more slashes in it, it is used unchanged*.

```
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo /usr/local/bin/python what_python.py
/usr/local/bin/python
2.7.6 (default, Feb 27 2014, 17:05:07) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)]
```

Ok.

*If the executable was not found on $PATH (or there was no $PATH environment variable), the original argv[0] string is used.*

```
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo PATH= python what_python.py
<empty line>
2.7.6 (default, Feb 27 2014, 17:05:07) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)]
```

Wrong. In this case statement from sys module's [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sys.html) is true – *If Python is unable to retrieve the real path to its executable, sys.executable will be an empty string or None.* .

Let's see if adding location of python's binary back to the `PATH` (after sudo had removed it) *fixes* the problem:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo PATH=$PATH python what_python.py
/usr/local/bin/python
2.7.6 (default, Feb 27 2014, 17:05:07) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)]
```

It does.

Related:

- Python issue [7774](http://bugs.python.org/issue7774) – sys.executable: wrong location if zeroth command argument is modified.
- Python issue [10835](http://bugs.python.org/issue10835) – sys.executable default and altinstall
- python-dev mailing list [thread](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-March/062453.html) – towards a stricter definition of sys.executable
- Stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/933850/95735) – how to find the location of the executable in C

Answer (score 1):

I think `/usr/local/bin/python` is the executable that is running. The version string is almost certainly compiled into `python`, so it is very unlikely to be wrong. Looking at the documentation for `sys.executable`:

> sys.executable
>
> A string giving the absolute path of the executable binary for the Python interpreter, on systems where this makes sense. If Python is unable to retrieve the real path to its executable, sys.executable will be an empty string or None.

The fact that `python` may be unable to retrieve this suggests that it is doing its own `PATH` search using the `PATH` sudo has set (which as per my answer to the previous question is not the same as the one it used to find the executable).

The only way to be certain here is to dig through the python implementation, but generally I would say that the version string is more likely to be the one you can trust. On the other hand though, `sudo` uses `execve` to execute the command (at least according to the `man` page). You must specify the full path of the executable to `execve` (some of the `exec` variations do their own `PATH` search, this one doesn't). Therefore it should be a no brainer for `python` to fill in `sys.executable`.

I don't know if there is any way to get the actual `argv[0]` for the `python` interpreter (`sys.argv[0]` is always the name of the script or `-c`), but this would be interesting to see. If it is `/usr/local/bin/python`, this would be a bug in `python`.

I think the best thing to do is just to set `secure_path` in `/etc/sudoers`, hopefully then you will get some consistency.

#### Update

Actually `execve` takes on argument for the executable path and then an `argv` array, so `argv[0]` is not necessarily `/usr/local/bin/python`. You can still find it out though by making a script like:

```
import time
time.sleep(60)
```

Then run it and get `ps` to give you the full arguments:

```
sudo python sleep.py &
ps -o args= -C python
```

Also to be sure which `python` is being run, you can do:

```
sudo ls -l /proc/PID/exe
```

while the program is running.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you start python interpreter, the shell goes to /usr/bin/python and executes it (try next: python -c "import os; print(os.environ['_'])").

Well then, as you can see yourself `ln -l | grep python` /usr/bin/python is a soft link to the python interpreter executable.

What I did was:

1. Install the last version of python (go to the website of python,
   download the last code and `configure && make && make install` )
2. Check location of this last version executable.
3. Erase /usr/bin/python soft link ##(you will need root permission
   sudo)
4. `ln -s <location` of last python version executable> /usr/bin/python
   ##(quite likely sudo needed)
5. Execute python from the command line.
6. import sys

sys.version ## it should be the last one.