# OSX: using bash to find python is different than using /usr/bin/env python

Tags: python, macos, bash

I don't know what to make of this.  If I ask my shell (bash) to launch `python` without giving it an exact path, it somehow launches the wrong program (or possibly the right program, but with the wrong `dylib`s loaded).  Yet, the output of `which python` and `/usr/bin/env python` both look just fine.

Here's an illustration of what I'm talking about:

OK, first of all, where is my `python` command coming from? Let's follow the symlinks. (BTW, Too bad `readlink -f` and `realpath` don't exist on OSX...)

```bash
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  68 Jan 18 11:44 /usr/local/bin/python@ -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
$ ls -l /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  7 Jan 18 11:44 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python@ -> python2
$ ls -l /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  9 Jan 18 11:44 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2@ -> python2.7
$ ls -l /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root  admin  25624 Dec  5 15:57 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7*
```

If I call `/usr/local/bin/python`, where does `python` itself think it is located?  And what version is it?

```bash
$ /usr/local/bin/python -c "import sys; print sys.executable; print sys.version_info"
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=11, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

OK, looks legit.  Instead of typing `/usr/local/bin/python`, what if I let `/usr/bin/env` locate `python` for me?

```bash
$ /usr/bin/env python -c "import sys; print sys.executable; print sys.version_info"
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=11, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Same thing.  No surprises so far.  OK, what if I just type `python`?  That should be the same as `/usr/bin/env python`, right?

```bash
$ python -c "import sys; print sys.executable; print sys.version_info"
/usr/local/bin/python
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=10, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

Wait, what?  `sys.executable` points to the **symlink**, and the version is wrong.  What's going on?

Why would typing `python` be different in any way from typing `/usr/local/bin/python`?

BTW:

- I double-checked my bash aliases, and `python` is not one of them. (`alias | grep python`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash keeps a cached lookup table in memory, which you can examine with `hash`.  If you add a program to your `PATH` with the same name as a program you have used before at a different location, `bash` will still remember the old location.  `env` obviously bypasses this cache; or you can remove it with `hash -r python`.

Also note that `which` is nonportable and often not the correct tool to use; `type` is specified by POSIX, and is built-in to any modern shell.

Answer (score 2):

When you run program from `$PATH` ( so, like `$ python` ) then it's `argv[0]` is set to just it's name ( eg. `python` ), not full path. And python 2.7 version of `sys.executable` [looks at `$PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22311100/898435) if `argv[0]` doesn't have backslash on beggining ( so, eg. when you run it like in last example ). And it seems that it's not resolving symlinks, just printing first found path.

As we can see [in python's code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Modules/getpath.c#l415), on OS X it uses `NSGetExecutablePath` to itself in `$PATH`. And on [Apple's site](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dyld.3.html) they say that `NSGetExecutablePath`

> That is, the path may be a symbolic link and not the real file.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  I think you're on the right track.  As tripleee's answer points out, I needed to run `hash -r python` to reconfigure the shell's path to python.  (I had just installed a new version.)  I think bash was still launching python from old location, but that location wasn't reflected in python's `sys.argv[0]`.  Therefore, `python` itself was using a bogus value for `sys.executable`.  Obviously, that breaks everything.

Comment: BTW, thanks for pointing to the relevant line in the python source. If that code is still the same in Python 3, it sounds like someone needs to submit a patch that check's the shell `hash` table instead of just searching `PATH`.